# nginx passing assets from S3

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I'm trying to configure Nginx to passing assets from S3.I have the below in the config but when am trying to access frontend, nginx return 404 on static resources. And nginx error log is empty. Can someone please advise what could be wrong with this conf. Thanks.

```
location ~* \.(ttf|woff|svg|ico|css|js|png|jpeg|html|json)($|\?) {
   set $s3_bucket        'bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com';
   set $url_full         '$1';

   proxy_http_version     1.1;
   proxy_set_header       Host $s3_bucket;
   proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
   proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
   proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
   proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
   proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
   proxy_buffering        off;
   proxy_intercept_errors on;

   resolver               8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
   resolver_timeout       10s;

   proxy_pass            https://$s3_bucket/$url_full;
}
```

Comment: give me a sample of an asset URL

Comment: did you specify bucket properly and setup files as public (without authentication) access? If you need to serve private files, generate the signed URLs first